# What happen if the code within a catch fails

Tags: c#, try-catch

Using c# code within a web application, I have a try catch statement in my code and within the catch I want to do several things such as email an administrator.

I am wondering what would happen if the email code or other code within the catch fails? Is there a way to handle a general exception in the application?

Comment: You could put another try-catch in that catch block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Description

1. There are 2 things you can do to catch unhandled exceptions. `Application.ThreadException` and `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`

   > **Application.ThreadException** Occurs when an untrapped thread exception is thrown.
   >
   > **AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException** Occurs when an exception is not caught.
2. Handle a exception inside the catch block.

#### Sample

1. `Application.ThreadException` and `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`

   ```
   Application.ThreadException +=
       new System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);

   AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += 
        new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
   ```
2. Handle a exception inside the catch block.

   ```
   try
   {
       // do something
   } 
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       try
       {
           // send E-Mail
       } 
       catch
       {
           // handle 
       }   
   }
   ```

#### More Information

- [Application.ThreadException Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx)
- [AppDomain.UnhandledException Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If an exception is thrown within the catch clause, it simply raises another exception. One way to solve it is to simply have a nested try, eg.

```
try {
  <stuff>
} catch(Exception e) {
  try {
    <email admin>
  catch(EmailException e2) {
    <stuff>
  }
  <stuff>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to handle the exception *within* the `catch` statement:

```
try
{
    // Do stuff
}
catch (SpecificException ex)
{
    try
    {
        // Try e-mailing
    }
    catch (AnotherException ex1)
    {
        // Write local log file
    }
 }
```

this will allow the program to continue.

However, if the program can't you can handle all unhandled exceptions at the application level and do something there.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you will have to surround the routine where you have your try catch with another try catch, or write your code in the catch statement surrounded with a try catch statement.

Answer (score 1):

you can try aplication exception, if it's fatal error. , though its become obsolete [Checkthis](http://weblogs.asp.net/pjohnson/archive/2006/04/12/442678.aspx)  now in .net framework.

[Application exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.applicationexception%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

```
public sealed class Product
{
  private String name;
  public String Name
  {
    get { return name; }
    set
    {
      if (value != null) name = value;
      else throw new UndefinedNameException();
    }
  }
  public sealed class UndefinedNameException : ApplicationException
  {
    public UndefinedNameException() : base("Name cannot be null") {}
  }
} // end of class Product
```

Answer (score 1):

If the exception is thrown in `catch` block it will be propagated the normal way exceptions are.

You will need the following code:

```
try 
{
  //code 
}
catch (SomeKindOfError e1)
{
    try 
    {
       // send email
    }
    catch (EmailError e2)
    {

    }
}
```

Your exception would be caught by any outer block where it is eligible, e.g. if you have:

```
try 
{
   // ...
   try {
      //code 
   }
   catch (SomeKindOfErrorThatIsNotEmailError e1)
   {
      // send email
   }
   // ...
}
catch 
{
    // your email exception will get caught here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am wondering what would happen if the email code or other code within the catch fails?

The exception thrown within `catch` will be handled by CLR Default Handler if not enclosed within another `try-catch` pair.

However `finally` will **definitely** execute. so you can use it to clearing or closing the resources.

> Is there a way to handle a general exception in the application?

within main method, write following code part:

```
try
{
    // write normal code
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    // if here exception occurs ... God Help.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is for a windows application

```
 static void Main()
            {
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += AppDomain_UnhandledException;

                Application.ThreadException += Application_ThreadException;
                Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);

            }
            static void Application_ThreadException(Object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.Message, "Application.ThreadException");
            }

            static void AppDomain_UnhandledException(Object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(((Exception)e.ExceptionObject).Message, "AppDomain.UnhandledException");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no incompatibily with the fact to use a `try` `catch` sequence in a `catch` snippet
Logically, you won't catch the same exception so you can know what part failed

Lot of guys gave u the code to use, accept one of these answers